# Reduce error type param pipe transform Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, reduce

I created a transform pipe to reduce a list of objects

```js
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: ListCount[], attr: string): number {
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
  }
}
```

this the model of ListCount :

```js
export interface ListCount {
  centre?: string;
  cause?: string;
  Time?: number;
}
```

but I have this error :

```
 error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ListCount'
```

Any help please

Comment: Why was this closed as a typo/not reproducible? I wouldn't be surprised if it's a duplicate but other than that it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [HTN answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66815361/5583283), using `attr: keyof ListCount` tighten the typings for the `attr` parameter but because `ListCount` has both `string` and `number` value properties you need to validate if the attribute you are getting from `b` is of type `number` using `typeof`.

```js
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: ListCount[], attr: keyof ListCount): number {
    return items.reduce((a, b) => {
      // get `attr` value from `b`
      const value = b[attr];
      // validate if type of `b[attr]` is number
      // - if so do the addition
      // - otherwise return previous `a` value
      return typeof value === 'number' ? a += value : a;
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `attr` is a string, so not a known property of `ListCount`

You can try:

```js
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: ListCount[], attr: keyof ListCount): number {
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have this errors :
```error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string | number'.
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.```

Comment: this the model of ListCount :
```export interface ListCount {
  centre?: string;
  cause?: string;
  Time?: number;
}
```

Comment: If you want to add `time` only, why do you need to use `attr`? Just do: `return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b.Time, 0);`.However, do not forget that `Time` can be undefined as well, what do you do in this case, make it like 0 ?  `return items.reduce((a, b) => a + (b.Time ?? 0), 0);`